# LaTeXing, Sublime, LuaLaTeX and biber

Tags: biblatex, sublime-text

While not a TeX question as such, I hope TeX.SE hostes Sublime and biblatex experts able to help.

I'm having trouble getting my template running the way it should. My main problem is that Sublime and Latexing are not recognizing my bibliography file, and i havent the foggiest why: i have formated it like `biblatex` says i should (at least i tried my best) and the bib file resides in the same folder as the template. When trying to import citation `Sublime` tells me:

> No source for importing citations available, please check your
>   settings.

I have tried with several classes, just to be on the safe side, and i've tried a gazillion variations to the biblatex options but the result is still the same.

The `lilyglyphs` package requires `xelatex` or `lualatex` to work so i have set `latexing` to compile with lualatex - biber - lualatex (2x), but alas...

Please help!

```
% \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\documentclass[a4paper,nobib]{tufte-handout}

%% Backend stuff
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%% Table stuff
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

%% Music stuff
\usepackage{xpiano}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs} % requires xe- or lualatex

%% Typography stuff
\usepackage{microtype}

%% Utilitys
\usepackage{lipsum}

%% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bib.bib}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% CUSTOM COMMANDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% META DATA
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\title{Bibliographies with biber and biblatex}
\author{Carl-Henrik Buschmann}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% DOCUMENT
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\maketitle

``Lorem'' ipsum dolor sit amet \autocite{buschmann:2015}.
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Bibliography (bib.bib)

```
@mastersthesis{buschmann:2015,
    author = Carl-Henrik Buschmann,
    title = The Musical Conventions of Star Trek,
    subtitle = The Search For Musical Syntax in Science Fiction,
    year = 2015,
    institution = Høgskolen i Nesna,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with LaTeXing or Sublime Text, but rather that you have some syntax errors in your bibliography file. Sometimes, running commands from the command line can help you see the problems. For instance, I tried running `biber` from the command line, and it told me there were syntax errors in your file. In particular, `biber` doesn't like the spaces in your entries; you need to surround those entries with `"` quote marks. The following bib file worked for me:

```
@mastersthesis{buschmann:2015,
    author = "Carl-Henrik Buschmann",
    title = "The Musical Conventions of Star Trek",
    subtitle = "The Search For Musical Syntax in Science Fiction",
    year = 2015,
    institution = "Høgskolen i Nesna",
}
```